# How to change the default opening level of this beautiful Multi Level Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is this beautiful Multi Level Push Menu on codepen and I want to make a little modification.

[Here is the link on codepen.](https://codepen.io/romswellparian/pen/aOJbOL?editors=1010)

The normal behavior is when you click on the hamburger button the menu shows up from the **All Categories** section right?

I want to open the menu from different depth so when you click on hamburger button the menu open in **Mobile Phones** section. does this make sense?! for instance if we store the class name of the **Mobile Phones** section element (which is ion-iphone) in a variable and this variable could be used as default opening section.

Here is the function where pressing hamburger button executes:

```
_openMenu: function(subLevel) {
      // increment level depth
      ++this.level;

      // move the main wrapper
      var levelFactor = (this.level - 1) * this.options.levelSpacing,
        translateVal = this.options.type === 'overlap' ? this.el.offsetWidth + levelFactor : this.el.offsetWidth;

      this._setTransform('translate3d(' + translateVal + 'px,0,0)');

      if (subLevel) {
        // reset transform for sublevel
        this._setTransform('', subLevel);
        // need to reset the translate value for the level menus that have the same level depth and are not open
        for (var i = 0, len = this.levels.length; i < len; ++i) {
          var levelEl = this.levels[i];
          if (levelEl != subLevel && !classie.has(levelEl, 'mp-level-open')) {
            this._setTransform('translate3d(-100%,0,0) translate3d(' + -1 * levelFactor + 'px,0,0)', levelEl);
          }
        }
      }
      // add class mp-pushed to main wrapper if opening the first time
      if (this.level === 1) {
        classie.add(this.wrapper, 'mp-pushed');
        this.open = true;
      }
      // add class mp-level-open to the opening level element
      classie.add(subLevel || this.levels[0], 'mp-level-open');
    },
```

I can't get the idea how it select the levels and how it opens the selected level.

look at this line:

```
// add class mp-level-open to the opening level element
classie.add(subLevel || this.levels[0], 'mp-level-open');
```

it seems that the above line of code is responsible for opening each level but when I change the `this.levels[0]` to `this.levels[1]` distortions happen ...

How can I open the desired content in this multi level menu?